# Restrict collisions to certain objects in Blender 3.0 (collision groups)?

Tags: physics

How can I restrict the collision modifier on an object so that it only interacts with certain objects?

I see in older versions of Blender this was possible with collision groups/masks, but I can't seem to find that option in Blender 3.0. Where has this been moved to, or what is the modern equivalent of this feature in newer versions of Blender?

Answer (score 2):

Put the active object in a collection, choose this collection under *Collisions > Object Collisions > Collision Collection*. Put the objects that are supposed to interact in the same collection:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I suppose you can only do something like this on cloth objects then?

Comment: @Perpetuum edit: sorry I miunderstood, what sort of object are you using?

Comment: That's ok, I was trying to use a softbody cage with mesh deform to add dynamics to another object. I wanted said object to collide with other objects in the scene without colliding with the cage itself, as that seemed to ruin the effect of the physics. However, it seems I can get a similar effect by substituting the softbody modifier with cloth, and simply turning off object collisions for the cage entirely. Was just wondering if this kind of collision grouping was possible with anything other than cloth, but it's not a big deal for the current situation. Maybe I'm just going about this wrong.

Comment: @Perpetuum, for softbody you have a Collision Collection on the top of the physics panel, you need to select the collection where the soft body object is, and also put the collision passive object in the same collection